# Is it possible to only iterate through assigned elements in a C array?

Tags: arrays, c, malloc

Say an array is allocated with 1 billion integers, but only 1000 elements there in the array are actually filled. I wanted to iterate through a C array, but ideally only with the assigned elements. I know there is a sparse matrix like stuff to do that, but then a second array is needed, I have to then maintain the length of the second array. so I would like to ask, is that possible to have it done without a second array?

Comment: why not use a hash table that maps `index` to `integer`?

Comment: is it mmaped buffer?

Comment: @tstanisl Hey, hashtable is actually a good idea, but the problem is that the number of assigned elements is not a certain number, and the "key" for hashtable is actually unique without being hashed. Will hash table be more efficient than the array way by searching and inserting values from the aspect of speed?

Comment: and the array is just a dynamic array allocated by malloc

Comment: do you want to iterate over elements in their index order? or maybe in their insertion order? The insertion order allows very fast insertion and search.

Comment: What I have to do with this data structure is that I would insert value according to a number, which is the index of the array for now, the key for hashtable later. Later I would have to iterate the assigned elements, but the order can be either insertion order or index order.

Comment: so basically, you need an efficient data structure for handling a set of about 1000 integers from range 1-1e9 ?

Comment: yes, exactlly^^

Comment: but actually, the number is not certain, can be 1000 but can also be 1000,000

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible. C doesn't have any built-in support for sparse arrays. There's no way to tell which elements have been assigned or not. You may want to use some other type of data structure, such as a linked list, so you only allocate the elements that are needed.

Answer (score 1):

You have three ways:

1. One value to be considered invalid. All unassigned elements should have this value.
2. Assigned elements have to be "in order" from the beginning of the array. You only need one variable to keep a number of the assigned elements.
3. Have an additional array where you mark values as valid or invalid. One bit is enough

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define NBITS(v)       (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(v))

int isvalid(unsigned long long *validArray, size_t pos)
{
    unsigned long long mask  = 1ULL << (pos % NBITS(*validArray));
    return !!(array[pos/NBITS(*validArray)] & mask);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be not  to simply store the values, but store a struct

```
struct DataPoint
{ 
   bool valid;
   int value;
}
```

Then ensure to initialize it to be invalid to start with.